# Whitespace in popup menu after CMFCPopupMenu::RemoveItem

Tags: c++, mfc, menuitem, popupmenu

I filter `CMFCPopupMenu` items with `nID` and `RemoveItem`. Menu is defined in the resources. When `OnContextMenu` occurs I do

```
CMenu* pSubMenu = menu.GetSubMenu(5);
if (!pPopupMenu->Create(this, point.x, point.y, (HMENU)pSubMenu->m_hMenu, FALSE, TRUE))
   return;
```

...

```
if ((nID == ID_TREE_ITEM_MAT...
    pPopupMenu->RemoveItem(i);
```

After the job done I see whitespaces where menu items were before. How can I avoid that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling

```
CMFCPopupMenu::RecalcLayout()
```

might work...